# How to make a <div> container width and height for each same as “the value of clientWidth and clientHeight in maximized window”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## **Summary**

I am trying to make a `<div>` container which width and height are each as same as “*the value of `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` in **maximized window***”. That is, the width and height of `div` container are **fixed**, and their values are each equal to ***the value of 100% width and 100% height when they are in maximized window***.

## **Demand**

In order to achieve it, maybe I need to use javascript to get the value of `clientWidth` / `clientHeight` in maximized window and then adjust the size of the `<div>` container. I may only use CSS layout to achieve it, too. So which is the best way to achieve it? And how can I do?

## **Questions**

1. How to get the maximum value of `clientWidth` / `clientHeight` (the value of `clientWidth` / `clientHeight` in maximized window) directly?
2. How to make a `<div>` container which width and height are each as same as “*the value of `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` in **maximized window***”?

## **Postscript**

I have tried using `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight` to achieve it. But `screen.availHeight` includes the height of the browser tabs and the height of the address bar, and `screen.availWidth` includes the width of scroll bar which is on the right side of the browser. So those are not what I want. Maybe `screen.clientWidth` and `screen.clientHeight` are what I have wanted. But both of them are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var screenWidth  = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0); //Max of page size vs window size, or zero
var screenHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

Comment: Hello,

I have tried using `clientWidth` and `innerWidth` too. But both values are floating while resizing the window. And what I need is  “the value of `clientWidth` in maximized window” and it's a fixed number.

Comment: You cannot get the clientWidth value of the maximized window until the window has been maximized. However, you can re-run the above code any time the window size changes by wrapping the code in a [`$(window).resize(function(){  //stick code here });` event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` and `wh` measurements to set the width and height of your div as that of your window's height and width

here is a snippet

```css
body{
  margin:auto;
}
#div{
  border:solid 1px;
  width:100wh;
  height:100vh;

}
```

```html
<div id='div'></div>
```

Comment: the border is a little thin and  it makes a little scrollbar on the window nevertheless,  without the border full fit is achieved

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your response. But I hope the size of the <div> container won't change after resizing the window. Where the size of the <div> container still remains at 100% width and 100% height of the maximized window.

Comment: if this is the only div it will readjust to fit the whole screen..if there are other divs below this div with the vh and wh measurement, then it will maintained the window height and width..my apologies for not clearing this up

Comment: trying adding another div below my example and you will see the results